# Problema ao preencher tabela HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Estou tentando carregar uma tabela HTML com dados de um BD SqlServer. Estou conseguindo recuperar os dados do BD, o problema esta na hora de carregar a tabela, que esta preenchendo com os nomes das colunas e não com os valores. Não estou conseguindo identificar o error no código, gostaria que alguém pudesse me apontar a onde estou errando.

**Trecho do JavaScript:**

```
function loadData() {
    tableBody = document.querySelector("#modelTable > tbody");

    const request = new XMLHttpRequest();  
    request.open("get", "http://localhost:52691//api/AppLock/run/all");

    request.onload = () => {
        const json = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
        populateTable(json);
    };

    request.send();

}

function populateTable(json) {
    console.log(json);
    // Clears out existing table data
    while (tableBody.firstChild) {
        tableBody.removeChild(tableBody.firstChild);
    }

    // Populate table
    json.forEach((row) => {
        console.log(row);
        const tr = document.createElement("tr");

        Object.keys(row).forEach((cell) => {
            console.log(cell);
            const td = document.createElement("td");
            td.textContent = cell;
            tr.appendChild(td);
        });

        tableBody.appendChild(tr);
    });
}
```

**Exemplo de JSON:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**A tabela esta aparecendo desta forma:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Poderia manda código JSON completo?

Comment: @Maury Developer acabei de editar a pergunta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O valor de `cell` no `forEach` do `Object.keys(row)` retorna apenas os nomes das chaves do objeto. Para pegar os valores de cada chave você precisa usar a notação com colchetes da chave em `cell` da variável `row`:

```
td.textContent = row[cell];
```

Comment: Problema resolvido. Obrigado.